# camera picture orientation in a camera app

Tags: android, image, camera, orientation

I have a picture orientation problem when taking pictures with camera API which is very common and has a common solution:

```
mRotation = getRotation();
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(mRotation);

Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setRotation(mRotation);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

but this solution is not working in all devices and the pictures is in a wrong orientation.
To solve it I deleted second part and moved rotation correction to after taking picture:

```
private static class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void>
{
    private WeakReference<CameraActivity> mActivityWeakReference;

    SaveImageTask(CameraActivity cameraActivity)
    {
        mActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(cameraActivity);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... params)
    {
        CameraActivity cameraActivity = mActivityWeakReference.get();
        if (cameraActivity == null || cameraActivity.isFinishing())
            return null;

        Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(params[0], 0, params[0].length);

        if (source == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(cameraActivity, "Captured image is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(cameraActivity.mCameraPreview.getPictureRotation());
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        File rootDir = new File(cameraActivity.getFilesDir(), cameraActivity.mNote.getId().toString());
        rootDir.mkdir();
        File imageFolder = new File(rootDir, StringUtils.getImagePath());
        imageFolder.mkdir();

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        File imageName = new File(imageFolder, StringUtils.getImageFilePath(String.valueOf(time)));
        FileOutputStream outStream;

        try
        {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(imageName);
            //outStream.write(params[0]);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This works for all devices I have tested however there is another problem with this solution: It takes long time, about 3000ms vs 50ms(when saving the byte array returned by camera). Is there any solution to this problem. wether the whole orientation problem or long time problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem

```
 ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
 int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                 ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

  Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
  switch(orientation) {

case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
    break;

case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
    break;

case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
    break;

case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
default:
    rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
}
```

rotateImage method:

```
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(angle);
return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), 
source.getHeight(),
                           matrix, true);
}
```

try this method i think it helps you

Comment: your answer is similar to my second code snippet in my question. the problem with that is when saving the Bitmap with this function: Bitmap.compress(), it takes long time in a weak device about 2000ms! while outStream.write(data) takes 50ms.